# How can I save checkbox in devexpress gridview?

Tags: gridview, devexpress

Does anyone know how to save checkmarks inside the devexpress gridview?

I set
`OptionSelection.MultiSelectMode` 
to
`CheckBoxRowSelect` 
and
`OptionsLayout.StoreAllOptions` 
to
`True`.

Whenever I close and reopen the form, the checkbox I just checked keeps getting unchecked. So is there a way to save checkmarks?

Answer (score 0):

Rows selected is not part of the grid layout. GridView has the built-in capability to save selected rows in the grid data source. To enable this capability, specify the [GridView.OptionsSelection.CheckBoxSelectorField](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridOptionsSelection.CheckBoxSelectorField) property as described at [Sync Selection with Data Source](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/16439/controls-and-libraries/data-grid/focus-and-selection-handling/multiple-row-selection-via-built-in-check-column-and-selection-binding#sync-selection-with-data-source).

If you need to save selected rows somewhere else, implement a custom solution. This is illustrated at [Data Grid for Windows Forms - How to preserve a View's state](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/e776/data-grid-for-windows-forms-how-to-preserve-a-view-s-state#RefreshHelperClass.cs(vb)).